# How can i replace the values in respect with with missing data with Zero?

Tags: python, pandas

### What I have:

I have this data set as example:

```
raw_data={"Date":["01.02.2021","02.02.2021","04.02.2021","05.02.2021","07.02.2021"],
          "QTY":[2,6,8,10,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=raw_data

         Date  QTY
0  01.02.2021    2
1  02.02.2021    6
2  04.02.2021    8
3  05.02.2021   10
4  07.02.2021    1
```

### What I would:

I would, that replace the `QTY` respect to missing dates with `0` like this:

```
         Date  QTY
0  01.02.2021    2
1  02.02.2021    6
2  03.02.2021    0
3  04.02.2021    8
4  05.02.2021   10
5  06.02.2021    0
6  07.02.2021    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `DatetimIndex` first by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and for add missing days use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
  
df = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('d', fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)     
        Date  QTY
0 2021-02-01    2
1 2021-02-02    6
2 2021-02-03    0
3 2021-02-04    8
4 2021-02-05   10
5 2021-02-06    0
6 2021-02-07    1
```